# Lambda expressions Map.computeIfPresent() and Map.merge()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a map. Key is String and value is a list of String. If a key is not present in map, I want to insert key along with its value which is a newly created list of one element. If that key is already present in map, I only want to update its value by adding one more element to that list. It can be done in plain Java. But I want to achieve it by using Java 8 `Map.computeIfAbsent()` and `Map.computeIfPresent()` methods. Alternatively, how can I do it using `Map.merge()` if that's possible.

```
Map<String,List<String>> listMap    = null;
listMap.computeIfAbsent(fiId, key ->    new ArrayList<>()).add("any value");
listMap.computeIfPresent(fiId, (key, values) -> values.add("any value"));
```

Below is my merge syntax.

```
listMap.merge(fiId, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("any value")), (key, values) ->   ??????);
```

For first case, because `values.add()` returns a boolean. How can I convert it into `List' ?

Comment: should be like this : `(l1,l2)->{l1.addAll(l2);return l1;}`

Comment: `listMap.merge(fiId, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("any value")),(l1,l2)->{l1.addAll(l2);return l1;});`

Comment: @HadiJ Thanks for helping out.

Comment: @TishyTash Would you mind closing it as a duplicate?

Comment: @YassinHajaj Done. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t get your question. `listMap.computeIfAbsent(fiId, key ->    new ArrayList<>()).add("any value");` does already do what you want. Why do you want to do the same with other methods?